# read objects in ibm cloud object storage using api key

Tags: object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

I am able to read files in bucket in COS using IAM token but unable to do the same using API key.
I have set the following key in my request header:

Authorization: {api key}

Should I set anything else? Note I am not using HMAC credentials.
below code has two options one with bearer token and the other with api key created for that Cos instance specifically for the bucket.

example code:

```
var request = require('request');
```

//using bearer token

```
var options = {

uri: 'https://{endpoint}/{bucket name}',
headers: {
'Authorization': 'bearer {token string}',
}
};
```

//using api key

```
var options = {
uri: 'https://{endpoint}/{bucketname}',
headers: {
'Authorization': '{{api key string for cos service id}',
}
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
console.log(error)
console.log(response.statusCode)
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
console.log(body)
}
}

 request(options, callback);
```

Comment: Are you encountering error messages? If so, please include them so that people can help.

Comment: I am getting 403 forbidden as response code..

Comment: Can you provide a minimum complete and verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Just use the ibm-cos-sdk npm library here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm-cos-sdk. You just have to do the following and you're on your way.

```
var AWS = require('ibm-cos-sdk');
var util = require('util');

var config = {
    endpoint: '<endpoint>',
    apiKeyId: '<api-key>',
    ibmAuthEndpoint: 'https://iam.ng.bluemix.net/oidc/token',
    serviceInstanceId: '<resource-instance-id>',
};

var cos = new AWS.S3(config);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this already but getting this 

error:nhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config

Comment: You're using the COS endpoint, the API key associated with your IBM Cloud account, and the COS resource ID?

Comment: Yes I have taken the endpoint section from the instance in IBM Cloud. I have also mentioned other parameters sch as apikeyid, authendpoint and crn.

Answer (score 0):

API key should not be sent in the Authorization header at all. Its a key for one time generation of the token. 
As A. J. Alger pointed out, I would suggest using some SDK (list provided below) to eliminate the redundant work. 
Regrading the error you are getting while using the Node JS sdk, please provide more details on it.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm-cos-sdk
- https://github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-java